# forEach function in JavaScript used for Button

Tags: javascript, html, button, bootstrap-4

New to JS, can someone point out where I made a mistake below? the button is not working.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<button onclick ="insertFunction()"> click me! </button>
<div id ="containerDiv">
</div>
<script>
 var textArray = [
 {name: "Harry"}, {place: "London"} ]
 
 function insertFunction() {
 textArray.forEach(function(value,index){
 var insertText = '<p>Hello' +value.name+'</p>';
 document.getElementBydID("containerDiv").innerHTML+=insertText;
 });
 }
 </script>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: You have a typo `getElementBydID` should be `getElementById`

Comment: "Not working" isn't diagnostic. Please always provide specifics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have misspelt the method "getElementById()". Here is the correct implementation

```js
var textArray = [{ name: 'Harry' }, { place: 'London' }];
function insertFunction() {
  textArray.forEach(function (value, index) {
    var insertText = '<p>Hello' + value.name + '</p>';
    document.getElementById('containerDiv').innerHTML += insertText;
  });
}
```

```html
<button onclick ="insertFunction()"> click me! </button>
<div id ="containerDiv">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<button onclick ="insertFunction()"> click me! </button>
<div id ="containerDiv">
</div>
<script>
 var textArray = [
 {name: "Harry",
 place: "London"},
 {name: "Andy",
 place: "USA"},

 ]
 
 function insertFunction() {
 textArray.forEach(function(value,index){
 var insertText = '<p>Hello ' +value.name+'</p>';
 document.getElementById("containerDiv").innerHTML+=insertText;
 });
 }
 </script>
 </body>
 </html>
```

You had typo in getelementbyid. Also your JSON can be modified like this if required.

Comment: If it's a typo there's a specific reason for closing.

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo in getElementById. did not catch this since I was using simple code editor!
Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of problems with logic and loop but first, the reason why your click event is not triggered is due to a syntax error

```
document.getElementById("containerDiv").innerHTML+=insertText;
```

**you are having D capital in getElementByID which should be changed to getElementById** and it will let you trigger the click event
But still, the loop has one logical error  and I am writing a corrected version of the loop and hope it will help you considering there is no intentional reason behind the loop and if so your solution ends in the first few line

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<button onclick ="insertFunction()"> click me! </button>
<div id ="containerDiv">
</div>
<script>
 var textArray = [
 {name: "Harry"}, {name: "London"} ]
 
 function insertFunction() {
 var insertText = '';
 textArray.forEach(function(value,index){
 insertText = insertText  + '<p>Hello' +value.name+'</p> <br/>'; 
 });
document.getElementById("containerDiv").innerHTML+=insertText;
 }
 </script>
 </body>
 </html>
```